# svn create trunk and branches

Tags: svn, merge, repository, branch, trunk

I used Visual SVN Manager to create a repository, but I didn't create /trunk /branches and /tags at first.
Now, I NEED to add these since the project has grown up ==> branching and merging is essential!
What is the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming there isn't a name clash, [create](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html) *trunk*, *branches* and *tags* directories, [move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) your current source code into trunk, advise everyone to [switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) their working copies to trunk, and you're good to go.

Comment: would all the history of development still be there ?
What i mean is after this transition, if a developer decided to revert to a previous version in history, would it be possible ? conflicts ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you svn move, rather than svn add+delete, history will be preserved. After the move, you will see a + sign next to the add operation in the log.